# my fragment is still in the UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

this is my first fragment which open a fragment through xml layout

```
public class ListFrag extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemClickListener
{
    Context c;
    List<ReferalRow> referal_RowItems;
    DoctorDaoImpl doctorDao;
    DoctorServiceImpl service;
    DoctorValidator doctorValidator;
    View layoutView;
    ListView doctoListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_refer_mangmnt, null);
        return layoutView;
    }
```

and this is my `activity_refer_mangmnt`.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="5dp" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:padding="2dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_refer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rightpanel_back">
 <fragment
     android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
     android:tag="detailfrag"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     class="com.example.app1.DetailsFrag" />
 </LinearLayout>
`</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my DetailFrag class

```
public class DetailsFrag extends SherlockFragment
{
    ExpandableListView detailList;
    TextView tvMessage;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_refer_view, null);
    detailList = (ExpandableListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ep_detail_view);
    tvMessage = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_textView);
    return contentView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(id==0)
    {
        detailList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvMessage.setText("Click on the item on the left panel to view the details");
    }
    else
    {
        detailList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and this is my onItem click listener in LIstFrag

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment lastFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detailfrag");
        if(lastFrag!=null)
        ft.remove(lastFrag);
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(c, DoctorDetailsFrag.class.getName(),arguments);
        ft.replace(R.id.detail_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

i need when first time i want to display a message in the right panel after click on the item in the list i want to disappear that message. but here the message is not remove from the fragment. its displayed in the backgrnd of new fragment. y it is?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null)
```

after you call: ft.remove(lastFrag);

Perhaps this link can help you to understand this transaction:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Another way is to to reuse your lastFrag when it's not null. Then you need a method in your DetailFrag that is called from your clickListener.